# Xpage Extension Library Rest Service return: http 200 Bad Request, Unable to read Unread Marks

Tags: rest, xpages, xpages-extlib

I coded an Xpage extension library rest service, and it worked until today, in my development enviroment it worked but not in prodution (same documents):
Here the response when ajax contact rest service:

```
 {
    "code":400,
    "text":"Bad Request",
    "message":"Unable to read Unread Marks",
    "type":"text",
    "data":"com.ibm.domino.services.ServiceException: 
    at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewNavigatorFactory$NOINavigator.getRead(RestViewNavigatorFactory.java:175)
    at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewItemFileService.writeSystemColumns(RestViewItemFileService.java:359)
    at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewItemFileService.writeEntryAsJson(RestViewItemFileService.java:308)
    at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewItemFileService.renderServiceJSONGet(RestViewItemFileService.java:280)
    at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewItemFileService.renderService(RestViewItemFileService.java:77)
    at com.ibm.domino.services.HttpServiceEngine.processRequest(HttpServiceEngine.java:167)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService._processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:242)
    at com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService.processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:219)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx$1.invokeContextCallback(AjaxUtilEx.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:862)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIDataPanelBase.invokeOnComponent(UIDataPanelBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.invokeOnComponent(UIComponent.java:878)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokeOnComponent(UIViewRootEx.java:1552)
    at com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx.renderAjaxPartialLifecycle(AjaxUtilEx.java:188)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.renderAjaxPartial(FacesServletEx.java:225)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:170)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:583)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1281)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:854)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:803)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:572)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1265)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:658)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:481)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:341)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:297)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
Caused by: NotesException: Unable to read Unread Marks
    at lotus.domino.local.ViewEntry.getRead(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewNavigatorFactory$NOINavigator.getRead(RestViewNavigatorFactory.java:173)
    ... 35 more
"
}
```

I have no idea what going wrong.
It just stop working

Comment: Have you checked your IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder for XPages logs that might give more information.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty That's what I've found : `06/03/13 11.52: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal
 at com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal.<init>(NoAccessSignal.java:35)...`

Comment: That error normally refers to an ACL rights issue. Make sure your web user has the rights to the database.

Comment: The possible differences between the working development copy and the failing production environment are: who can run Xpages (I think you wouldn't get to the error spot with this), who has rights to the database (relatively common for production and development to have different ACLs) and server setup. (I'm a developer, so I just yell down the hall, "Your server's broken!") This is the reason it's good to have a "test" environment that duplicates production, since development never does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using one of the provided examples to just get a documentCollection? If not, are unread marks on for your production database? Does your REST call have access/does your database allow anonymous access via REST if not?

Your error is here:
      at lotus.domino.local.ViewEntry.getRead(Unknown Source)

This method of the NotesViewEntry class looks for the user name in order to know whether to return a boolean telling if the entry has been read. If no user is specified, it returns for the current  user, and that may be the server or who is authenticated in the REST service.

Also, I find this http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd8forum.nsf/5f27803bba85d8e285256bf10054620d/2f8ee50784b70b06852577dc0050efeb?OpenDocument saying unread marks are not working in some releases, but I've not been able to verify it.

If you can remove the line calling for getRead() and run it, that will confirm for you.

Cheers,
Brian